# Django queryset : I have a Employee model with below fields

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

```
Class Employee(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     age = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     salary = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I need to write a queryset to fetch all the details with an additional field called Group. So Group will set "A" if salary is grater than 10000 else "B".

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried and what does not work?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a job for Case/When https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case

Try something like:

```
Employee.objects.annotate(
    group=Case(
        When(salary__gte=10000, then=Value('A')),
        default=Value('B'),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in model class as property:

```
@property
def group(self):
    if self.salary > 10000:
        return 'A'
    else:
        return 'B'
```